# Generic function parameter restricted to a property of T

Tags: typescript, generic-function

I have a `uniqBy` function defined thus:

```ts
export function uniqBy<T>(a: T[], key: any): T[] {
    const seen = {};
    return a.filter(function (item) {
        if (item) {
            const k = key(item);
            return seen.hasOwnProperty(k) ? false : (seen[k] = true);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

This strongly types my return value based on the input array, but I would also like `key` parameter to be strongly typed so that I get compile-time errors if I try to pass in a property that doesn't exist on `T`.
example of current usage:

```ts
uniqArray = uniqBy(this._checkups, x => x.CatDescription);
```

`_checkups` being an array of the following:

```ts
export interface Checkup {
  id: string;
  CatDescription: string;
  ProcessTitle: string;
  MsgProcessID: number;
  MsgDate: string;
  MsgStatus: number;
  MsgText: string;
  MsgAction: string;
  MsgEntityID: string;
  MsgEntity: string;
}
```

I would like it if trying to do the following:

```ts
uniqArray = uniqBy(this._checkups, x => x.NonExistantProperty);
```

gave me a compile-time error (and IntelliSense on the property completion). How would I define `key` in the parameters in order to do this?

This would return an array of items with only unique values of `CatDescription` (taking the first object with a `CatDescription` in the event of duplicates).

I don't know what this is called, it's not a `Predicate<T>` as that is for filtering and returns a boolean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like as second parameter you pass callback but you don't have a type for it so you an just give it a type `(val: T) => T[keyof T]`

```
export function uniqBy<T>(a: T[], key: (val: T) => T[keyof T]): T[] {
    const seen = {};
    return a.filter(function (item) {
        if (item) {
            const k = key(item);
            return seen.hasOwnProperty(k) ? false : (seen[k] = true);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Then by adding non existent key it will give you an error

```
uniqArray = uniqBy<Checkup>(this._checkups, x => x.NonExistantProperty);
```

Comment: You probably want `T[keyof T]` as a return type, not `keyof`.

Comment: @georg perfect, I was about to comment that I was getting an error on valid properties.